# Entity Designer Database Generation Power Pack generates datetime and not datetime2 for ProviderManifestToken = 2008

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, ddl, edmx, ef-model-first

Im having trouble with the DDL-generation from EDMX using the "Entity Designer Database Generation Power Pack" add-on. It generates datetime-columns instead on datetime2 even though ProviderManifestToken is set to 2008. Can it be fixed? I don't want to do this manually all the time because Im using the model-first-approach...

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm connected to SQL Server 2008, the ProviderManifestToke is set to 2008 and the connection string even specifies Type System Version=SQL Server 2008. I still get "datetime" in my generated SQL. Is this expected behavior and we're supposed to manually edit the script?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found how to specify to E4 to output a datetime2 instead of a datetime.

You need to update the .tt file that you use to generate your DDL.

Complete answer can be found here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/adodotnetentityframework/thread/22ee46ca-9b6e-44a4-b5ed-b7e89a68a9b8